# Is there a way to ignore custom CA common name in Node.JS tls?

Tags: node.js, ssl, ca

I develop decentralized p2p app with Node.JS.
Each client has own master x.509 cert and signed cert for each device (node). When client A wants to add client B to a friends list, he just add his master cert in own CA list and trust all node certs of Client B. It works as I expected, but there is one problem - "common name" colission in CA list makes trusted signed certificates untrusted. Two clients with the same Common Name can't reach each other, and I think if Client B make the same CN as Client C, Client A wouldn't connect with Client C because of B&C CN colission. In my program will not be any domains and SNI and I want to identify client only by his certificate.
So, how can I avoid problem caused by CA common names colission? As temporary solution I added random uuid for CN in certificate generator, but it isn't an option.

Comment: *" ... but it isn't an option"* - why? But to address your original point: the subject (where CN is part of) is used in finding the issuer CA based on the issuer information in the certificate. Thus different CA need to have different subjects.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so it's not suitable for fully decentralized platform where peers are CA for their friends. As i described, problems with CN collisions can ruin some peers connectivity while anyone can write a pseudo-random UUID.

Comment: Which basically means that your approach conflicts with existing standards. In this case it is probably better to change your approach instead of trying to adjust software stacks to no longer follow the standards.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks, i get your point